# Problem on one-to-one correspondence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $S$ is infinite and can be brought into one-to-one correspondence with the set of integers, prove that there is one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and $S\times S$

**Definition:** A set $S$ is said to be infinite is there is one-to-one correspondence between $S$ ans a proper subset of $S$.

This is problem from I.N.Herstein's "Topics in Algebra". Intuitively I know that this is true, however I cannot to prove it rigorously. Can anyone show how to do it, please?

Comment: Do you have a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Unfortunately it was my main problem during the solution. I was thinking that firstly we need to construct one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$. Second the same for $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ and $S\times S$ and after applying composition we get one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and $S\times S$, right? P.S. I was not able to construct mapping between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ which is onto and one-to-one.

Comment: @EricTowers, Could you help me to construct bijection $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You probably know that there is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, so all you really need is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. Try drawing $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$; you'll get a grid. Then look at the diagonals of the grid.

Comment: @KevinLong, Yes I have already done it. I have drawn this grid but i cannot find the bijection explicitly. This confuses me

Answer (score 0):

(Note:  I default to "maps on the left".  Herstein goes the other way.)

**Lemma**:  Let $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a one-to-one correspondence.  Then $g: S \times S \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ given by
$$  g(x,y) = (f(x), f(y))  $$
is a one-to-one correspondence.  (Note that one-to-one correspondences are invertible and their inverses are one-to-one correspondences.)

**Proof**: Standard exercise.  (You indicate this is not where you have an obstruction.)

**Lemma**:  There is a one-to-one correspondence between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.  (Call the map $h:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.)

**Proof**:  (This is a standard construction between the nonegative integers and pairs of nonnegative integers.  See [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).  This gives a one-to-one and onto mapping.  (If SE allowed SVGs, there's be a copy of the image at the link here.  This is an instance of a picture being worth a thousand words.)  You adapt it into a map from integers to pairs of integers by, where the diagram shown has red arrows, instead iterating through the points in quadrant II that are reflections of the points accumulated since the last red arrow, skipping points with $0$ second coordinate.  Then for negative integers, mapping them to the reflection through the origin of the image of the positive integer of the same magnitude.  In detail, splitting by red arrows and signs:
$$  0 \mapsto (0,0) , $$
$$  1 \mapsto (1,0), 2 \mapsto (0,1), \\
   -1 \mapsto (-1,0), -2 \mapsto (0,-1) , $$
$$  3 \mapsto (2,0), 4 \mapsto (1,1), 5 \mapsto (0,2), 6 \mapsto (-1,1), \\
   -3 \mapsto (-2,0), -4 \mapsto (-1,-1), -5 \mapsto (0,-2), -6 \mapsto (1,-1) , $$
$$ \vdots $$
)

**Theorem**:  There is a one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and $S \times S$.

**Proof**:  Since $S \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{h} \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{g^{-1}} S \times S$ is a composition of one-to-one correspondences, there is a one-to-one correspondence between $S$ and $S \times S$.  (This uses Lemma 1.2.2, that compositions of one-to-one maps are one-to-one and compositions of onto maps are onto.)